# How to "Select By Location" in ArcGIS Server JavaScript API

Tags: select-by-location, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, spatial-query, query-task

Is it possible to perform the equivalent of "select by location" in the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API v4.x? The use-case is "find features in Layer 1 which are within x kilometres of features in Layer 2".

Here are the options I've considered:

- a [QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-QueryTask.html) with [Query.geometry](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-Query.html#geometry) - this will query an entire layer, but only has the option to query against a single geometry *object*, not another *layer*
- [GeometryEngine.intersect](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#intersect) - only works between 2 geometry *objects*, not 2 *layers*
- The [FindExistingLocations](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/find-existing-locations.htm) spatial analysis service, which seems to require special [licensing](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/getting-started.htm) which I don't have (I don't have access to ArcGIS Portal on this project)
- Use the GeometryEngine.intersect approach in a JavaScript loop - which would require comparing every feature in both layers against each other (?)

I'm a little surprised that something so commonplace in a desktop GIS doesn't seem to be easily achievable in a web map. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a better answer, here's what I've come up with.

For each feature in Layer 2:

- `GeometryEngine.buffer` the feature's geometry to create the "within X km" buffer
- run `QueryTask.execute()` against Layer 1, where `query.geometry` is the buffer polygon
- [batch the QueryTasks](https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/implementing-an-async-queue-in-23-lines-of-code) to avoid overloading the server with too many concurrent queries
- de-duplicate the returned features (if there are overlapping buffers, features will be returned multiple times)

Comment: What about adding a [`GeometryEngine.Union`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#union) between the buffer and the query? then you get a dissolved buffer and can query only once.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion and it may work well for some cases. After testing, however, I found that it's actually a lot slower to run one mega-query than running a series of smaller queries. Also a series of smaller queries means I can show a progress bar. But many thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can add Sketch widget to create a graphicslayer and use that geometry to select features in target featurelayer.
[Sketch widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However in my case I want to "find features in Layer 1 which are within x kilometres of features in Layer 2" rather than finding features which intersect with a polygon drawn manually by the user